# How do I determine which program is rerouting traffic on port 80?

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding

A while back, I wanted to redirect all port 80 traffic on an Ubuntu server to port 3000 for a Rails app. Instead of just using iptables, I googled around and found some other way to do it (I can't imagine why I didn't find iptables first), but now I can't remember how I did it! Is there some way to track what's going on so I can turn it off? There are no rules in iptables and traffic never gets to apache.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

No, you normally just need to load the new ruleset. See: askubuntu.com/q/161551/266 . But don't despair. Iptables can be confusing. – Stefan Lasiewski

Comment: _I learned today that you need to reboot the server for deleted iptables rules to cease effect._ -- No, you normally just need to load the new ruleset. See: http://askubuntu.com/q/161551/266 . But don't despair. Iptables *can* be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following command:

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

It should output something like this example:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1138/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      850/portmap
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1607/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55091           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      910/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1467/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      992/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1565/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3813/transmission
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      992/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1565/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::7000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3813/transmission
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           850/portmap
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:662             0.0.0.0:*                           910/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1467/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1467/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           3697/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*                           3813/transmission
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54746           0.0.0.0:*                           910/rpc.statd
```

As you can see above the first entry, TCP port `3306`, was opened by `mysqld` process having `PID # 1138`. Just look at your entry for port 80 and see what service and process ID is running on it. You can than verify this using `/proc`, enter the command:

```
# ls -l /proc/1138/exe
```

You will replace `1138` with whatever PID is on port 80 for you.

It should output something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2010-10-29 10:20 /proc/1138/exe -> /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

This will give you the location of that program that is running behind it.

If you have port forwarding up using SSH then you need to reconfigure your sshd_config file located here with a text editor...vim or gedit will do the trick:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

In this file you should see an entry like this just simple comment it out or change it to no.  To comment it out put a `#` symbol in front of it then save and close:

```
# Port forwarding
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Comment: Regarding your comment below.  Do you have an SSH service running doing port forwarding?  If that is the case then you need to configure your ssh_config files and remove the port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what process is listening on port 80:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep -w 80
```

It should hopefully be obvious from the output what it is.

Comment: No luck. If I have apache running, then it shows up, and if I stop apache then nothing is listening on port 80. Traffic is still passing through port 80 and getting redirected to port 3000 before it hits apache.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't set up that iptables rule after all?

Comment: You're right. I hadn't rebooted and didn't realize that the iptables rules weren't immediately removed.